# git: non-deprecated way of listing skip-worktree files?

Tags: git, git-index

The internets recommend `git ls-files -v` to look for files that were marked as skip-worktree.

Documentation for `-v` flag of `git-ls-files` says it's similar to `-t` flag which is "semi-deprecated".

Is there a non-deprecated (and/or scriptable) way of looking for skip-worktree files?

Comment: But it isn't -t. Why are you assuming that it's also marked as semi-deprecated?

Comment: -t is semi-deprecated because there are almost always superior alternatives for scripting purposes as well as more user-friendly alternatives.  The only difference between -t and -v is lowercase letters for assume unchanged.  However, neither superior alternatives for scripting purposes, nor user-friendly alternatives for that are listed.